# log4j fails to write into file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, log4j

I'm using Spring + Log4j. I can see my logs in Eclipse console, but Log4j failed to write into target file.

My web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>60000</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My log4j.properties: the target file is D:/home/site/wwwroot/logs/swinguserver.log

```
### set log levels ###
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

### Settings for Console ###
log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [ %t:%r ] - [ %p ]  %m%n

### Settings for File ###
log4j.appender.LOGFILE = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File = D:\/home\/site\/wwwroot\/logs\/swinguserver.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern = %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [ %t:%r ] - [ %p ]  %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.DatePattern = '_'yyyyMMdd'.log'
```

The java code I use to test Spring + Log4j, the log level is INFO and the log content is : JSONController.getShopInJSON(), name = xxxxxx

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class JSONController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(JSONController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        logger.info("JSONController.getShopInJSON(), name = " + name);

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});

        return shop;

    }

}
```

When I visit the test url in browser, I can see the desired log in Eclipse console:

[image]

[image]

However, when I check D:/home/site/wwwroot/logs/swinguserver.log, there is nothing about the test log:

[image]

Any suggestion? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I imported the wrong Logger package... Nothing is wrong with the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.FILE.File= D:/home/site/wwwroot/logs/swinguserver.log

**Try above two lines insted of below two lines in your program**

log4j.appender.LOGFILE = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File = D:/home/site/wwwroot/logs/swinguserver.log

Comment: Hi vikky, would you please further explain why use FileAppender instead of DailyRollingFileAppender? Thank you.